# Is it possible to use babeltrace Python API (or any other software tool) for reading “live” LTTng traces?

Tags: python, api, trace, lttng, babeltrace

I am using LTTng to trace an application. To read the LTTng trace data I am using Python API [babeltrace](https://diamon.org/babeltrace/docs/python/).

I switch-on the LTTng tracing and the trace data is stored in a folder. I use Python API babeltrace to read the **recorded** traced data. Now, is it possible to read the LTTng trace data in `live` mode? either using babeltrace or any other software tool (Python binding).